# Appear obscure line after statusBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, statusbar

I have a problem with navigationBar. It is transparent. After scrolling appear obscure line under statusBar. What is it?
[image]

Method for transparent:

```
- (void)makeNavbarTransparent:(BOOL)transparent {
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
}
```

[image]

Comment: you need to tell more about your view heirarchy. Looks like a problem with the Pull to refresh control.

Comment: @Shubhank without pullToRefresh I have this problem to.

Comment: you need to further debug this. can you check what happens if you hide the navigation bar ?

Comment: @Shubhank if I hide the navigationBar, lines appear too

Comment: can you upload a basic reproducible sample and upload on github ?

Comment: @Shubhank unfortunately, I can not repeat this a bug in the new project.